# What is Qing Liu's rule of index and reference in "Algebraic Geometry and Arithemetic Curves "

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am just so confused about Qing Liu's way of referencing definition/lemma/theorem. For example, on Page 166, he said Definition 2.3.11 but I couldn't find this in his book. Is there a rule of his referencing or it's just a typo? What does 2.3.11 means? Sometimes there is one definition in one chapter and a lemma in the other chapter that has the same number, x.x.xx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be definition 3.11 from chapter 2, which you will find on page 44. Besides, take a look at the **Numbering style** section from the preface.

Comment: Thank you very much! Apologize for my negligence.